# Multiplicative Sum Solver not functioning

Tags: java, sum

In a class I am taking, we are supposed to solve equations that look like this ([] = digit):
`[][]*[][][]=[][][][]`
Where each digit 1-9 can only be used once.
The one the code I have made is solving is `[][]*[][][]=4396`

I have code that is free of errors, but will not do the intended action

Disclaimer: The code does not check if the digits 1-9 are only used once, that is up for the human to decide (for now, please do not add this function in any example code)

Here is the code:

```
public class MK1 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    //the full sum
    long sum = 4396;


    long guess = 10000, guessCopy, otherSum = 0;
    short count = 0;

    //the digits used to guess the number
    long[] digits = new long[5];

    while(guess <= 99999)
    {

        //sets the different indexes of digits[] to the digits of guess
        guessCopy = guess;
        count = 0;
        while(guessCopy > 0)
        {

            digits[count] =  (guessCopy % 10);
            guessCopy = guessCopy / 10;

            count++;

        }            


        //determining if the guess is correct 
        otherSum = ((digits[4]*10) + digits[3]) * ((digits[2]*100) + (digits[1]*10) + digits[0]);

        if(otherSum == sum)
        {

//Print out digits that work
            for(int i = 0; i > digits.length; i++)
            {

                System.out.println(digits[i]);

//print out the separation between different solutions
                if(i == digits.length -1)
                {

                    System.out.println("next possible solution");

                }    

            }

        }

        //iterating the guess
        guess++;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, can you try to explain it a little more?

Comment: If the answer was 29*815=4396, then the code should output: 2 9 8 1 5 next possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, your digits are backwards in your `otherSum` calculation line.  Also, your loop to print digits has the wrong comparison sign, it should be `i < digits.length`.  Here is working code you should replace in:

```
        //determining if the guess is correct 
        otherSum = ((digits[0]*10) + digits[1]) * ((digits[2]*100) + (digits[3]*10) + digits[4]);

        if(otherSum == sum)
        {

//Print out digits that work
            for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++)
            {

                System.out.println(digits[i]);

//print out the separation between different solutions
                if(i == digits.length -1)
                {

                    System.out.println("next possible solution");

                }    

            }

        }
```

You might also want to consider switching your output to look better, right now its very vertical and tough to interpret.

Comment: Thank you! For the life of me, I couldn’t figure out what was wrong! Also, when calculating otherSum, it should not matter the order because each digit will end up cycling from 1 to 9. I don’t know why I couldn’t figure out that it should have been < instead of >. Oh well..